# Literal Array can't be traverse by Jquery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

ok i do have this literal array declared as seen in a firebug screenshot below

[image]

now i tried to traverse it by using `jquery.each();`

this my code

```
$.each(window.feeditems,function(key,val){
   alert('pass OK');
   console.log('index:' + key + ', ' + 'value:' + val);
}); 
console.log('overview:' + window.feeditems);
console.log('length:' + window.feeditems.length);
```

ok so with the code above, the TODO inside the callback of `$.each` doesn't execute as expected the `length` is `undefined` when its printed it on the console.

well in a very strange case as i printed the `window.feeditems` in the firebug it displays my literal array completely like what displayed in the screenshot above.

now my question is how i can traverse this kind of array? i know `jquery.each()` relies on the `length` property of the array, and im also thinking of using for loop but how i can loop without knowing its size?

**UPDATE 1**

i recheck again the length and transfer it somewhere, it returns length zero, but put it with the next line the content checker code, it still contains the contents of the array.

**UPDATE 2**

Any possible workaround so I can traverse this array on the runtime without accessing the nodes manually in the code? for example using a for loop?

Comment: Try it without the window prefix ?

Comment: When/where are you setting `window.feeditems`? I assume you are trying to access it before it is set (ajax?) and Firebug is somehow live-evaluating the reference. You can only iterate the array *after* it has been set, i.e. inside your Ajax callback (if you use Ajax).

Comment: @adeneo ok let's give it a shot..

Comment: @FelixKling i set the window.feeditems already before executing the code above, as i wrote a checking whether the window.feeditem contains something by `console.log('overview:' + window.feeditems);` and it shows something exactly with the screenshot(of course only the contents)

Comment: Triple check... that's a common issue.

Comment: @adeneo already tried it.. not working T_T

Comment: @FelixKling yeah i checked it.. i wrote the checking code already, it seems really to be initialized, but the logger for length and checking of the feeditem elements doesn't work

Comment: @FelixKling corrected already the mistyped code, thank you

Comment: Kolink got the answer... arrays only work properly with numeric keys.

Answer (score 3):

An array only accepts numeric indices. You appear to be defining string keys instead, which will not count as part of the `.length` or show up in a `.each()`.

Instead of starting your definition with `[]`, use `{}` to allow string keys. However, keep in mind that you still won't be able to use `.length`.

Comment: thank you, well i receive this data from a 'json_encode()' from a external php file. so my only idea is its literally declared as json.

Comment: @Mahan: `json_encode` would certainly not produce such an output since such JSON would be invalid.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry for not clarifying my side, well the indices is produced by `json_encode` been modified in the client-side upon received

Comment: @Mahan: Well, then don't modify it they way you do ;) Don't create an array with string indicies. Either create an object and keep a separate variable of the count if you need it or create a proper array.

Comment: @FelixKling well still im still looking for a possibility that the length can still be counted. but for now maybe i need a code redesign thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript `For...In` Statement

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_for_in